# Finding "hidden" solutions to a simple complex system of linear equations

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve the following system of linear equations in the complex plane:

$$\begin{cases} z_1 = -iz_2 \\ z_2 = iz_1 \end{cases} $$
I know the solution, it's $z_1 = 1, \space z_2 = i$, but i can't find a way to prove it, it seems like the solution is "hidden". If someone could provide a proof (and maybe an explanation on what's going on), I would much appreciate it.

Comment: That's only one of the solutions. $z_1$ can be any complex number and then $z_2$ has to be $iz_1$. To see this, just use the first equation to elimenate $z_1$ from the second equation.

Comment: Hint: $z_1=z_2=0$ is also a solution, as is $z_1=i$, $z_2=1$. How can you have more than one solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to see when you bring everything on one side and order by variables:

$z_1+iz_2=0$

$-iz_1+z_2=0$.

Now, multiply both sides of the second equation by $i$. You get:

$z_1+iz_2=0$

$z_1+iz_2=0$.

That's twice the same equation! What this means is that you really only have one *distinct* equation for two variables,  i.e. you are undetermined.
Again, what this means is that you can choose any value for $z_1$, which then fixed $z_2=i z_1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe I didn't see that!
I was very tired and it drove me crazy :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$e^{i\frac{\pi}2}=i\Rightarrow\frac 1i=e^{-i\frac{\pi}2}=-i\rightarrow\boxed{\frac 1i=-i}$

Answer (score 1):

Both the equations $z_1 = -iz_2$ and $z_2 = iz_1$ are the same equation and can be converted in to each other.

Let, $$z_1=r_1(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)=r_1e^{i\varphi}$$ $$z_2=r_2(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)=r_2e^{i\phi}$$

Using $z_1 = -iz_2$ $$r_1e^{i\varphi}=-r_2e^{i\phi}$$

Using Euler's formula $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}=-i$ $$r_1e^{i\varphi}=r_2e^{i\bigl(\phi-\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)}$$

Also, magnitude of both $z_1$ and $z_2$ is same $\implies$ $r_1=r_2$

$\therefore$ There may be an infinite solution to this problem because of relation $\varphi=\phi-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and this relation still holds true if the magnitude of both $z_1$ and $z_2$ is same $\implies$ $r_1=r_2$.